# Why is my WCF client timing out sometimes when trying to connect to the WCF Service on localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service hosted within a Windows service.  The client that is connecting to it is on the same machine so I would expect it to take long to connect and definitely not timeout.  For some reason when I start the client and it tries to connect to the service it times out.  This only happens occasionally, but enough where it is annoying since the entire app relies on a good connection tot he service.  What could cause a client on the same machine as the service time out when connecting?  Here are the app.config files from the host and the client.

Here is the client config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IWCFService" closeTimeout="00:00:10"
      openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:30"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF/WCFService/"
    binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IWCFService"
    contract="WCFService.IWCFService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IWCFService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

And the service config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WCF.WCFService" behaviorConfiguration="WCFBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="WCF.IWCFService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint
      address="mex"
      binding="mexHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCF/WCFService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Is there anything I can do to make the client connect better and make the the connection more stable in general?  Change the binding? Anything?

Comment: Are you sure the timeout is happening during connect, and not already during processing your service operation? You might want to post the full exception text (+stacktrace) and/or look at your problem using [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add one more endpoint with "netNamedPipeBinding" that was originally designed for local calls.